# belongs_to on Activerecord of Rails creates lots of queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the Article model and ArticleLike model which records the user likes the article or not.

The articleLike model belongs to Article and the definition is as the following

```
class ArticleLike < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
end
```

If I use ArticleLike.where(:article_id: XXX), ActiveRecord will send a raw query like

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE article_id = XXX
```

Is that possible to avoid ActiveRecord to send this raw query to my DB?
Sometimes, I only need to select some fields that don't need any join, but Activerecord always join(includes) the tables if I set belongs_to in the model.

Many thanks.

Comment: Simply `ArticleLike.where(:article_id: XXX)` shouldn't do the query you mention. Could you run `ArticleLike.where(:article_id: XXX).to_sql` and show us the result?

Comment: sorry. I found the query was sent because I new the model and save. If my Article table has lots of columns, is it possible to avoid to use SELECT * for foreign key check? I think it only need to use SELECT id FROM article to check the consistency. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any validations that trigger this query? As it is in the question saving an ArticleLike shouldn't do the query. Please update your question to reflect the latest findings and question you have.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can reduce the number of columns by using either `select` or `pluck` (depending on if you want multiple or only one column).

eg:

```
ArticleLike.where(:article_id: XXX).pluck(:id)
=> ['123', '456']
ArticleLike.where(:article_id: XXX).pluck(:id).to_sql
=> "SELECT id FROM article WHERE article_id = XXX"

ArticleLike.where(:article_id: XXX).select("column_1, column_2").to_sql
=> "SELECT column_1, column_2 FROM article WHERE article_id = XXX"
```

More detail on how to use Active Record query interface is here:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Answer (score -1):

I think [find_by_sql](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Querying/find_by_sql) can solve what you're trying to get.